# Patterns for Docker DB Snapshot

Tags: mysql, database, docker

What is a good pattern for making a Docker image containing a database snapshot?

Essentially I want to create a Docker image that when it starts has a database running in a particular state.  I'm not really bothered about persisting any changes to the database (it should be possible to write to the database, I just don't care whether the changes hang around after a restart).

I've seen a couple of repos on the Docker Registry that will load data from a dump on startup, but this is quite slow.  I've worked out how to create an empty database image, set it running, add data to it, then commit it to get a snapshot, but this feels quite convoluted.  It feels like there should be a better pattern for doing this.  I'm hoping someone else has had this problem and has come up with a good pattern for it.

In my particular case I need to use MySQL 5.1 so none of the repos on the Docker Registry quite work because its an old version, but I'm happy to copy one and adapt it.

Comment: I'd be keen on a good easy to use pattern for this too. My first though was to use ``docker save > db-snapshot.tar`` and alter on ``docker import < db-snapshot.tar``.